# Print tag with access password - Zebra ZT410

Tags: rfid, zebra-printers, zpl

I'm trying to print a RFID Transponder with access password, but with no success.
I tried to set it from Zebra Designer Pro but it doesn't work..i can re write the EPC even if i don't put the correct password.

Here you can find a PRN from my label:

```
^XA
^MMT
^LS0
^BY96,95^FT52,107^BXN,6,200,0,0,1,~
^FH\^FD[mybarcode]^FS
^FT165,78^A0N,45,45^FH\^FD[mybarcode]^FS
^FT34,138^A0B,31,31^FH\^FD01-2018^FS
^FT48,145^A0N,31,31^FH\^FDMyCustomerLabel^FS
^RFW,H,1,18,1^FD400012345678901234567890123456789012^FS^RZ41265237,E,P^FS
^RZ41265237,A,P^FS
^WVY
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

Any suggestion or tutorial? I prefer to set it correctly directly from Zebra Designer and not from a ZPL file.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try to set lock in EPC memory bank, you are setting AccesPassword but the EPC is not protected, use Lock or PermanentLock, in case of apply PermanentLock in any memory bank you will not be able to change the content...

Comment: Hi, i've already tried to set the Lock in the EPC memory.. nothing happened, i can re write the tag too